# Only one set of values is being displayed

Tags: c#

```cs
private void btn_öppna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult resultat = dlgÖppnaFil.ShowDialog();

    if (resultat == DialogResult.OK) {
        //Empty list
        dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Clear();

        //Open file
        FileStream inStröm = new FileStream(dlgÖppnaFil.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader läsare = new BinaryReader(inStröm);

        //Read number of sellers
        int antalSäljare = läsare.ReadInt32();

        //Read values for every seller and display them
        for (int i = 0; i < antalSäljare; i++) {
            string namn = läsare.ReadString();
            double personnr = läsare.ReadDouble();
            string distrikt = läsare.ReadString();
            int antal = läsare.ReadInt32();
            int nivå = läsare.ReadInt32();

            Säljare nySäljare = new Säljare(namn, personnr, distrikt, antal, nivå);
            säljare.Add(nySäljare);

            dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare;
        }

        läsare.Dispose();
}
```

Only 1 seller is being displayed, while the input was several

Comment: Have your tried debugging your code?
I assume `antalSäljare` is greater than 1.
How often does the loop run?
Can you provide an example of your file structure?

Comment: I'd move the assignment (`dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare`) out from the for cycle. And, while debugging, check values of `antalSäljare` and `säljare.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare;` after the loop. Since it is always the same instance of `säljare`, successive assigments `dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare;` will not update the dgv because the `DataSource` does not notice the change.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < antalSäljare; i++) {
    string namn = läsare.ReadString();
    double personnr = läsare.ReadDouble();
    string distrikt = läsare.ReadString();
    int antal = läsare.ReadInt32();
    int nivå = läsare.ReadInt32();

    Säljare nySäljare = new Säljare(namn, personnr, distrikt, antal, nivå);
    säljare.Add(nySäljare);
}
dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare;
```

Alternatively, set the data source null before re-assigning it.

```cs
dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = null;
dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare;
```

But if you do this inside the loop, the dgv will flicker.

---

Also use a [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration) instead of disposing `läsare` explicitly:

```cs
using var läsare = new BinaryReader(inStröm);
```

and drop the line

```
läsare.Dispose();
```

This is safer, as `Dispose` will always be called. Even if an exception should occur or if the method was left prematurely with a `return;`. This also applies to `using var inStröm = new FileStream(...);` as @JHBonarius pointed out.

Comment: the filestream should probably also be put in a using statement